# Is it possible to do Ampscript Lookup based on the partial search?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to do a lookup from a landing page, so was wondering if I need to provide the exact search term, or it also works for the partial term.

Comment: Please provide more information and any existing samples or ideas you have for this issue.

Comment: I need to do a lookup from a landing page, so was wondering if I need to provide the exact search term, or it also works for the  partial term.

Answer (score 2):

AMPscript Lookups are a direct match only.  You may want to look towards [Rows SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm) or some [API calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm) to use things that are a bit more flexible.

AMPScript Lookup will only do 'equals'.

E.g.

```
%%=Lookup('PostalCode','City','PostalCode',46016)=%%
```

The above will look in the DE 'PostalCode' for the field 'City' when the field 'PostalCode' is equal to 46016.  Any further parameters added on are also EQUALS and are added on in the AND context.  There is no option for OR in Lookups.